# Use XSLT to reveal Page XMLNS

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I am creating a quick-ref stylesheet for my XML files, and part of that reference is seeing which xml namespace I am using in each file.

For example, the start tage of gen_info.xml is:

```
<GeneralInfo xmlpre="Gen" xmlns="http://www.mrinitialman.com/">
```

Displaying the attribute "xmlpre" is easy enough:  `<xsl:value-of select="@xmlpre" />` .  But `<xsl:value-of select="@xmlns" />` seems to do nothing.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You are missing the fact that `xmlns="http://www.mrinitialman.com/"` is not an *attribute* but a [*namespace declaration*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl). It puts the `GeneralInfo` element and its descendants in a *[default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting)* whose URI is  `"http://www.mrinitialman.com/"`.

You can use the [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-namespace-uri) function to retrieve the namespace URI of a node. If - as it seems* - you are in the context of the `GeneralInfo` element, then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>
```

will return:

```
http://www.mrinitialman.com/
```

Note that an element can be in a namespace inherited from an ancestor element or determined by a prefix attached to its name; IOW, the `namespace-uri()` function returns the namespace URI of the argument node, not of a namespace declaration.

--
*(*) It's not clear from your question how you get into the context of the `GeneralInfo` element, since it is in a namespace.*